# Python script from php doesnt give any output

Tags: php, python

This is my php script

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</head>
  <body>
    <?php
 $command=escapeshellcmd('~/PycharmProjects/Test_1/wiki_update.py 2 2>&1');
 $output=shell_exec($command);
 echo $output;
 ?>
</body>   
 </HTML>
```

I get no output when I run it through the browser.

When I change the 
`$command=escapeshellcmd('whoami');`

it outputs as NOBODY,

I granted permission to nobody for that python script still no output.

I am using xampp for linux and php script in htdocs/xampp.

Comment: Try dumping `$command` as a string and running it manually using your shell.

Comment: it works through shell .. php trial.php runs perfectly but not through browser which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't need to change your command to run `python`?

```
 $command=escapeshellcmd('python ~/PycharmProjects/Test_1/wiki_update.py 2 2>&1');
```

You also might try specifying absolute path - the `~` alias changes based on current user (which  is the web server's user, not yours).

Comment: You need the absolute filepath. On my system, `~/Sites/script.py` is the same as `/Users/jeffstephens/Sites/script.py`. You can use `pwd` on the command line to get the full path!

Comment: What did you try? Paste your shell call here.